# Wireless Induction coil wired to USB

Tags: wiring, inductive, wireless-charging

I'm not an electrical engineer so forgive any obvious ignorance that may be unwittingly baked into the question.

***Background***:

My kids have these Disney Infinity Light FX figures that, now that Infinity is being shut down, I think I'll want to end up displaying in their room.

[image]

Since there are 7 of these things, but only two can live on the pad at any given time, I need to find a different solution to allow for "always on" light from all of them - (ie - all 7 lined up on a bookshelf)

The Infinity base uses NFC as far as I can tell.

I've been noodling on this and done some reading on the Qi standard and devices but it looks like most of the new Qi devices are v1.2 which contain foreign object detection - ie - it won't send power to non-phone devices.

***Question:***

So - I thought, *what if I bypass the Qi controller all together and just directly shoot power through the coil* - that should work...right?

[image: wireless coil]

Can I wire a wireless induction coil to a USB cable and expect it to:

a) receive power

b) not burn through the table

c) deliver inductive power to another NFC type device?

I've taken a quick first stab at this via wire-nuts. A stripped USB cable to a coil and plugging the USB into a small iPhone transformer plugged into the wall. It didn't work like I expected but nothing exploded so that is good :|

Is my expectation here even correct?

[Couldn't I just tear apart the figures and hard-wire the LED to a battery? - Sure - but that isn't as fun and I don't want to tear up the figures](http://infinityinquirer.com/2016/01/08/how-i-got-my-disney-infinity-light-fx-figures-to-glow-without-a-base/)

Comment: Electromagnetic Waves are just that, waves. A DC voltage will not keep creating them. To get any meaningful power in you need to find out the resonant frequency of the puppets and drive a coil at _that exact_ frequency.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get some success by opening the infinity charging base and wire some extra coils to it. Afterall, it already has all the necessary electronics and I'd be surprised if those things used something as sophisticated as QI, it's probably closer to a transformer sawn in half with some basic electronics in the base to drive it at a frequency much higher than the mains (something like 20kHz vs 50/60Hz), probably not much different to the innards of your phone charger.

Comment: Interesting suggestion - I have two bases so one can definitely be sacrificed to try this out